# Azure Rest Api recommendedElasticPools always returns Internal Server Error 500, Is there anyone facing this issue?

Tags: rest, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-management-api, azure-management

When I tried other rest apis for Azure Mangement, it works without any issue. But when I try this recommendedElasticPools , I am getting internal server error all times.

```
{
  "code": "InternalServerError",
  "message": "There was an internal server error that occurred during this request.",
  "target": null,
  "details": [],
  "innererror": []
}
```

Comment: From the error response, we could not find any useful info. Which method (`Get`, `Get Databases`, etc.) does not work from [Recommended Elastic Pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/recommendedelasticpools) REST API? Have you tried to access [resources.azure.com](https://resources.azure.com), choose "recommendedElasticPools" under your database server to see whether you could retrieve the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

We had a problem with this API that should be fixed now. Thanks for reporting this. The API you were calling is on the deprecation path and I recommend using new API instead:

/subscriptions/{SubscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{GroupName}/providers/Microsoft.sql/servers/{ServerName}/elasticPoolEstimates/